# How to make 3 images stay in the same line responsive and hover effect

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, hover

I am using a template to make a website and i am not very good at css. However i have 3 images that i want to stay in the same line, have hover effect and fit the screen for different resolutions.

I found bits of what i want on the internet but i never really could fit them together to get this results.

From what i know hover effect doesn't work on mobile devices so i think i should use 2 css. One for mobile and one for computers and tablets. Something like when resolution <300 no hover. else do hover.

Please correct me if i am wrong. The images have no other formats, the code is `<img src="">`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us some code attempts so we can help you solve your problem.

Comment: #cos {width:100%;
   padding-left:10px;
 background-image:url(../img/csm.png);
font-size: 0; line-height: 0;

 }

 #cos:hover {width:100%;
 background-image:url(../img/csm2.png);
font-size: 0; line-height: 0;
} for the responsive thing i didn't do anything because they already go one under the other, but it should be nice if they can align in the same line.

Comment: What does your hover effect _do_? If it would not be a problem if it is just “missing”, then no need to _“use 2 css”_. (Which there isn’t anyway, keyword: Media Queries.) Apart from that, your question is too vague for any definite answers.

Comment: Before using it as an image i use inputs to display the images. The hover effect is used when you move the mouse over the image loads another image. I am sorry then for the vague question, please tell me what further info you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll want to have different stylesheets, since you should be able to do this in a nice responsive single CSS file.

This should get you started. Obviously you'll want to add [classes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp) to these on your proper site `class='inline-image'` or something similar.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Example.jpg' />
    <img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Example.jpg' />
    <img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Example.jpg' />
</div>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
div {
    /* to keep all the images on the one line*/
    white-space: nowrap;
}

img {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
}

img:hover {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/CVSvh/

Comment: Thanks for the response it's been very useful. Other problem was from the container i just realised. This clean formatting it was just what i was looking for. I will see later if it is responsive.